# Can “du tout” be used positively?

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot

For example, if I wanted to say “Is it different at all?” would that be “C’est différent du tout ?” or is that not possible?

Comment: What do you mean by: Is it different at all? Do you mean: different in relation to something else? Without context, your sentence is not very meaningful...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nope, you have to say *"Est-ce réellement différent ?"* or *"Y a-t-il la moindre différence ?"*.

Comment: You could also say "Est-ce seulement différent ?" which is similar to "Y a-t-il la moindre différence ?" Or "N'y a-t-il aucune différence ?". If you really want to translate the "at all" you can say "N'y a-t-il vraiment aucune différence du tout ?", but this is very insisting, like if you're asking a confirmation for the second time, usually the "du tout" isn't used.

Answer (score 6):

You could, but only on the condition you changed somewhat the question and asked instead a negative question, that is whether there is not any difference (then a comma may  be used for an equivalent formulation).

Is there not a difference at all ?

- Il n'y a pas de différence du tout ?
- N'y a-t-il pas de différence du tout ?
- N'y a-t-il pas de différence ? Du tout ? [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Du+tout+%3F&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDu%20tout%20%3F%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2CDu%20tout%20%3F%3B%2Cc0)